# why $.ajax not execute

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my code `$.ajax()` not working and so relevant script not execute.

please help me to resolve this problem!

my code that have problem:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var span_id1 = '',
            span_id2 = '',
            span_id3 = '',
            up_name = '',
            up_price = '',
            up_dis = '',
            _color = '',
            compOp = true,
            operation = '';
        //alert(operation + ' ' + $(this).attr('data-id'));
        $("a").on("click", function() {
            operation = $(this).text();

            if (operation === "Delete") {
                alert('Delete....');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "delete_Ajax.php",
                    method: "get",
                    data: {
                        "id": $(this).attr('data-delid')
                    },
                    success: function(resp) {
                        $("tr[data-id = " + resp + "]").slideUp(500, function() {
                            $(this).remove();
                            alert('..........................');
                        });
                    }
                })
   ...
```

and relevant script `"delete_Ajax.php" :`

```
<?php
die('exit..........');
use App\Model\DB;

$d_f =$_GET['id'];

$query = DB::Connect("tblproducts")->delete("id",$d_f);


if ($query)
    echo $d_f;

?>
```

Note: message statements (alert, die) is placed for checking hit points; first alert is execute but "die" and second alert is not execute. Also DB is a defined class.

the part of my HTML code that include relevant links:

```
<div data-title="OP">
  <a data-delid ='<?=$product['id']?>' href="#" >Delete</a>
  <a data-id = '<?=$i?>' data-edtid ='<?=$product['id']?>' href="#" >Edit</a>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your html code for button click?

Comment: Do a `console.log('test');` as the first action in your click-callback and see if the event works at all. Btw, have you checked if you get any errors in the console? You should probably also change the selector to a specific class instead of running this on every single click on every link on the page.

Comment: ...also, is the delete link loaded through ajax?

Comment: check your console for errors, if you find any post it so that you can let know what the actual issue is

Comment: Have you debug the XHR request?You don't have handler for failure and/or complete on ajax request (you only got success).

Is url "delete_Ajax.php" right (http 200 status)?

To have further checks i would edit php endpoint to `echo $_GET['id'];` and die.

In ajax request i would add complete handler with console.log(resp).
Also i would check if $(this).attr('data-delid') is fine. (i would recommend `$(this).data('delid')` )

Comment: Also i see in php string variable ( $_GET['id'] ) is not parsed to int before DB query. Maybe this will fix something `$d_f =(int)$_GET['id'];`.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me! I checked suggested solutions but none of them solve the problem :(